# How to insert column in Joomla table

Tags: mysql, joomla

i have a problem in inserting a varchar in column in a table in joomla. 
I know that there is a syntax

ALTER TABLE joom_virtuemart_categories_en_gb
ADD short_desc varchar(1200);

But how do i do it in joomla query? Here is my code.

Hope you can help me. thanks

```js
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->insert('short_desc')
 ->from('joom_virtuemart_categories_en_gb');


$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no special syntax for alter command, you need to use that as you use for core php :

```
 <?php
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query='ALTER TABLE `#__virtuemart_categories_en_gb` ADD `short_desc` varchar(1200)';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->query();
 ?>
```